# Woocommerce automatically add product to cart conditionally

Tags: woocommerce, checkout

I am running a platform to sell two kind of products

- eLearning products (can be bought as standalone)
- webinar products (mandatory to have eLearning bought in the past or buy elearning together with webinar)

I need to implement a function, that if a customers adds a webinar product to the cart, it should check if the user is signed in and has already bought the eLearning product in the past.
If so, he may continue to purchase the webinar as a standalone product.

If not, it should automatically add it to the cart as well (because it is mandatory to buy both products simultaneously).

If the customer later removes the automatically added product manually from the cart again, the checkout should not be possible and an error message should be shown that this certain product can only be bought together with the other.

I have already searched for plugins but none of the existing solutions seem to solve exactly this task and installing a huge plugin just for a simple if-clause might also not be the right way to archive it.

My php skills are very limited, so I am trying with pseudo-code:

Add to Cart:
If customers ads product "webinar to the cart
Check if product "eLearning" is in the cart as well or bought in the past
if not, add product "eLearning" to the cart

Checkout:
If only product "webinar" is in the cart, but product "eLearning" isnt and also not bought in the past, then show custom error message and disable checkout button.

Thanks in advance in helping me out with this!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that i use in some projects. Here i dont block checkout button or other not 100% bullet proof solutions. I am just forcing on removing additional product from cart to add it again. When user remove the bundle product then he can remove the additional product.

```
function check_cart_for_bundle_product() {
    $bundle_product_id = 33; // Our bundle product 
    $additional_product = 16; // Our additional product which must be in the cart to complete
    
    $product_cart_id = WC()->cart->generate_cart_id( $bundle_product_id ); // Products in cart have unique ID
    $in_cart = WC()->cart->find_product_in_cart( $product_cart_id ); // We search in cart by this unique ID
    if($in_cart) {
        //If user is not customer we want to add this additional product
        if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
            WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $additional_product );
        } else {
            //If current user is customer we want to check if he already purchased the additional product
            if ( !wc_customer_bought_product( '', get_current_user_id(), $additional_product ) ) {
                WC()->cart->add_to_cart( $additional_product );
            }
        }
    }
}
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart','check_cart_for_bundle_product');
```

Comment: Hey, 
thanks for quick help.

I have copied the code, changed the ids to my product variations and tested it in inkognito tab logged out, but the elearning course wont be added to the cart at checkout.

I am adding the product to the cart via a individual link 

https://example.com/checkout/?add-to-cart=12110&quantity=1

Might this be the reason?
But I also tries to change the action to "woocommerce_before_checkout_form" instead of "before_cart".

Comment: I have tested ?add-to-cart way and its working. Can you debug $in_cart does it match $product_cart_id ? Or if you have other functions or plugins that modify the cart ? Its tested on storefront theme as i always do and its working.